# What is the Process for Re-certifying Flight Hardware?

Tags: reuse, testing

I was [reading about how we reused the water tanks because they were still within their certified life-time](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36450/why-use-water-tanks-from-a-retired-space-shuttle) and had two questions:

- When would a certification become **VOID**?

  - I'd assume if the water tanks accidentally took a fall they'd not be certified still.
  - What are some other examples of events that can void a certification?
- When an event occurs altering the suitability of flight hardware how is it re-certified?

  - I'd assume there's some sort of inspection, could someone outline what it'd be?
  - You may use the example of the water tanks being dropped, what would NASA do?

You may also consider the [toppled NOA satellite](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/43/NOAA-N%27_accident.jpg/1920px-NOAA-N%27_accident.jpg) as a case study too if you wish. I'd like to know what all they had to do to consider it as "certified" again after the incident.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I've observed, the general process works like this:

1. **A Non-Conformance Report (NCR) is generated.**  These are applicable for everything from an unexpected scratch or tool mark on a surface to a system-level failure.  The NCR identifies the "is" vs. "should be" state of a component.
2. **A Material Review Board (MRB) convenes.**  This is a group of engineers and managers who make decisions in a structured way regarding NCRs.  From here, it's case-dependent.  It may involve specific analysis, or it may just be a series of discussions.  It all depends on the specific nonconformance.
3. **The NCR is dispositioned.**  Again, case dependent.  The disposition is determined by the MRB.  Typical disposition outcomes:

   - **Use as is.**  Analysis shows the nonconformance does not affect safety or mission success -- no corrective action is necessary to certify the part for flight.
   - **Rework the part.**  Case dependent.  Could be as simple as redrilling a hole in the right location, buffing out scratches, etc.
   - **Use as is, issue drawing rev.** In the case of a misdrilled hole, for example, create a drawing rev showing where the hole was drilled so that there is traceability between the drawing and what was manufactured.
   - **Scrap.** The component is too far gone.  Toss it out and build a new one.  Depending on the source of the NCR, it may be a build to print, or there may be a redesign.

Comment: +1, A couple of things to add: A) the MRB is usually given total authority over the future of the part and may direct the project office to examine, test, repair etc.  B) there is usually a distinction drawn between "re-work" such as your first example and "repair" which is closer to your second example of buffing to remove a scratch. The difference lies in that "re-work" is re-application of the same processes used in the original build whereas "repair" uses additional (authorised) processes that were not needed for an original build.